# Why airflow scheduler not triggering my dag?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I was trying to schedule an airflow dag that given a start date it will trigger that dag after every scheduled interval. This is what my dag definition looks like.

```
with DAG('Some Dag',
         start_date=datetime(year=2020, month=12, day=23),
         schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1, hours=5, minutes=0),
         catchup=False) as dag:
```

Doesn't it mean that the DAG will run on 2020/12/24 at 05:00:00 UTC? But in reality, it isn't triggering at that moment.

I know I can easily achieve this via a Cron expression. But I want to do it without a Cron expression.